# In my Todo ReactApp I am using flux. with useEffect I add a Listener but when the Todostore updates the page does not rerender. Why not?

Tags: reactjs, store, flux

Below is my TodoList Component. with useEffect I add a listener when the component first mounts and remove it after the component mounts. But when I add a to do the page does not rerender/update. When I call the store I see that the store did update with the new todoitem. What am I doing wrong?

Todolist component:

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import todoStore from '../Store/TodoStore';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import * as TodoActions from '../Store/TodoActions';

function TodoList() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoStore.getAll());

    const onChange = () => {
        setTodos(todoStore.getAll());
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        todoStore.on('change', onChange);
        console.log('count: ', todoStore.listenerCount('change'));
        return () => todoStore.removeListener('change', onChange);
    }, []);

    const todoComponents = todos.map((todo) => {
        return <TodoItem key={todo.id} text={todo.text} complete={todo.complete} />;
    });

    const createTodo = () => {
        TodoActions.createTodo(Date.now());
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Todo List</h1>
            {todoComponents}
            <button onClick={createTodo}>Create!</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoList;
```

todoStore:

```html
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import Dispatcher from './TodoDispatcher';

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.todos = [
            { id: 123, text: 'shopping', complete: false },
            { id: 412, text: 'laundrey', complete: false },
        ];
    }
    getAll() {
        return this.todos;
    }

    createTodo(text) {
        const id = Date.now();
        this.todos.push({ id, text, complete: false });
        this.emit('change');
    }

    handleActions(action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'CREATE_TODO':
                this.createTodo(action.text);
                break;
            case 'RECEIVE_TODOS':
                this.todos = action.todos;
                this.emit('change');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore();
Dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore));
window.todoStore = todoStore;
window.Dispatcher = Dispatcher;
export default todoStore;
```

create action:

```html
import Dispatcher from './TodoDispatcher';

export function createTodo(text) {
    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        type: 'CREATE_TODO',
        text,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't rerender the page because it did not see that the store updated because the onChange had a reference to the previous state of the store.

I changed the onChange function so that a new array is created every time the store updates. something like this:

```html
    const onChange = () => {
        setTodos([...todoStore.todos]);
    };
```